how can I destroy 3 screen from StackNavigator history and after navigate to first one screen?
I have Navigation history like this :
Ad Screen
Profile Screen
Settings Screen
SocialSettings Screen
After save settings on SocialSettings Screen I want to remove from history screens: Profile , Settings, SocialSettings , and Ad screen to be showed

If you want to remove a certain number ( 3 in your case ) of screens, you can use :
navigation.pop(3);

pop
Pops the current screen from the stack and navigates back to the previous screen. It takes one optional argument (count), which allows you to specify how many screens to pop back by.
Documentation

If you want to return to the first screen in the stack, removing all others, use :
navigation.popToTop();

popToTop
Pops all of the screens in the stack except the first one and navigates to it.
Documentation

I suggest using the following
 navigation.popToTop()

More info
